# Hangouts Chat Pub/Sub Bot only receiving Mentions in Room

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-hangouts

We are building our first bot for Hangouts Chat to support JIRA Server (https://github.com/seibert-media/hangouts-jira-bot) and I had to notice that Events in Google PubSub only get sent when the bot receives a direct message or get's mentioned in a room, but not for every room message.
Is this intended behavior or are we doing something wrong.

Comment: If like me you would like to see this feature added maybe a comment on the feature request will help.  -->  https://issuetracker.google.com/75245758 Allow internal bots to see all messages, not just mentions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the current intended behavior for Hangouts Chat. There is no way to have any sort of RTM socket, so everything in Hangouts Chat is currently event driven by @mentioning or dming a bot.

Comment: Well, that's sad. I thought bot's are able of reading every message and then decide like it is the matter with any other chat solution.